# show viewController based on login

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am learning IOS development and I have a simple structure question. I have a `UITabBarController` tabbar uinavigation in the app delegate. I have an account tab and I am wondering how do I show content based on wether or not the user is logged in. I have the user singleton data model, and I can switch between view controllers once the account tab is loaded, but my question is how do I determine the view before it loads. Do I just use `viewDidLoad`, check the model and then redirect?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` seems like a logical place to check the model and reconfigure the view's content based on whether the user is logged in or not.  At that point you can decide how you want to display a login view.

Comment: Is there something like a custom container controller? viewDidLoad just seems to be a not so elegant solution.